# GetIndexParameters() empty on Dictionary property

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to get some info about a class I'm exporting to excel. It loops through the properties to get their values.

I want it to also be able to handle indexed types like `List`s and `Dictionary`s. However, the `GetIndexParameters()` method on the property is returning none. Am I using this wrong?

Here you can see that `prop.Property` (which is a `PropertyInfo`) is showing the value as a `Dictionary<int, decimal>`, but the `indexParams` has 0 length.
[image]

Loop logic (slightly modified for SO, partially pseudocode)

```
foreach (var prop in ExportingPropertiesInOrder)
{
    //detect if it needs to have indexing applied.
    var indexParams = prop.Property.GetIndexParameters();
    var isIndexed = indexParams.Any();
    if (!isIndexed)
    {
        //get value for property for export
    }else{
        //loop through indeces, get each value
    }
```

Comment: There is a difference between an indexer property and a property returning something with an indexer. In your case, you have the latter, which is why the property itself has no parameters. It returns, however, an object which has an indexer. If you were to look at that object, and find the indexer on that, then you would find the parameter types you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property which is shown on screenshot is `Dictionary<int, decimal> TierValues`

it is NOT an indexer, so `GetIndexParameters()` method on the property is returning empty array

`Dictionary<int, decimal>` type itself HAS indexed property `Item`